# Como se agrega la tabla cotizacion?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert, table

Tengo las siguientes dos tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se agregara una cotizacion para despues agregarle en detalleCotizacion los productos que tiene dicha cotizacion. Mi duda es, al agregar la cotizacion el subtotal, iva y total se agregan como cero y ya que tenga detallesCotizacion se actualizan o se dejan null? o se realiza de alguna otra manera?

Comment: Eso depende de las reglas de tu negocio.. si es una tabla de cabecera te diria que se llenan... pero puede que no este completa... no es algo que te podamos contestar asi a la ligera....

Comment: Esos son campos calculados y los campos calculados no se guardan en la bd. Por qué guardarías esos datos en la cabecera? Qué pasa si editas/eliminas un producto del detalle, o le ofreces un mejor precio al cliente en uno de los productos? Tendrías un trigger para que se actualice la cabecera cada vez que esto ocurra? Voto por cerrar la pregunta por ser demasiado amplia

Comment: Podria ser una opcion calcular esos tres campos desde mi interfaz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a las reglas del negocio que describes, tienes una sola opción, guardas el valor de *"subtotal"*, *"iva"* y *"total"* en 0 ya que tienes una cotización abierta (con detalles o no) y cuando tengas que actualizar los detalles de tu tabla **detalleCotizacion**, estos hagan un update a tu tabla **Cotizaciones** con el cálculo de los montos.

La solución está basada en el proceso en dos fases que estableces.

Comment: Me hacen comentarios sobre que esos 3 valores no se guardan en la bd, que son campos calculados, puede ser una opcion viable?

Comment: @HiramF es dependiendo de cómo estés manejando tu data, generalmente aún a pesar de ser campos calculados, nada te impide hacer un update a tu tabla del encabezado cada vez que modifiques un detalle. Como se te indicó antes, es una respuesta que puede tener muchas variantes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda